# Dicionary intersect keys with list and get in result dicionary with values at the beggining LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a problem I cant make a Linq query which intersect my dictionary keys with list, and back to the origin dictionray without this which are gone.

```
var gg = request
    .Number_Name
    .Keys
    .Intersect(_context.Users.Select(x => x.Phone))
    .ToDictionary(t => t);
```

I tried something like this, but it doesnt work.

Comment: does this provide you with an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685142/c-sharp-dictionaries-intersect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

1 - Get keys

```
var keys = request
    .Number_Name
    .Keys
    .Intersect(_context.Users.Select(x => x.Phone));
```

2 - Get new dictionary

```
var newDic = request
    .Number_Name
    .Where(k => keys.Contains(k.Key))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Or

```
var newDic = request
    .Number_Name
    .Keys
    .Intersect(_context.Users.Select(x => x.Phone))
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => request.Number_Name[v]);
```